# Word file icons are blank

Tags: microsoft-word, office365

I'm using Office 365. And I **noticed that the Word file icons are blank.** Excel, Powerpoint, and others are ok.

I've already tried reinstalling and modify the default applications. Nothing fixed the problem.

**1) See how it is in Windows Explorer?**

[image]

**2) Inside Word is ok,the icons appear.:**

[image]

**3) In standard applications, only the .asd extension appears. It does not allow modification.**

[image]

**How to fix this problem?**

Comment: I assume you have selected Word with the “open with” context menu option? Have you tried to simply reinstall Office 365? Cant read the text in the screenshots…

Comment: Thank, yes, I already did that and it didn't work. I already removed Office and reinstalled it. I tried the open with option

Comment: Try running “assoc  .docx=Word.Document.12” in an elevated command prompt. Then within properties for the file click “Change” and select Word, then perform a system reboot

Comment: When you double-click on one of the .doc files to open it, does it open in MS Word or a different software?